# Ajax not loading properly: Jquery, Php

Tags: jquery, html

Everything in the following code works except it does not show anything while the processfeed.php executes..  I need help understanding why.  Some background on this..  It executes in a 580 x 130 Iframe..  and processfeed.php has a javascript redirect back to where it all starts, which is a text area with a post button basically..  like i said, everything works except the loading gif..

```
    <body onLoad="loadingAjax('myDiv');">

    <script>
    function loadingAjax(div_id)
    {
        $("#"+div_id).html('<center><img src="images/ajax_loader.gif"></center>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "processfeed.php?<? echo   "loggedinuser=$loggedinuser&message=$message&private=$private&userto=$userto&feedpic=$feedpic&  feedpictmp=$feedpictmp";?>",
            data: "loggedinuser=" + loggedinuser,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
    }
});
}
</script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

LOL, whoever just made an account and commented on my post, it disappeared when you deleted your account..  I didn't get to read all of it.

Also, I'll eventually get around to detecting strings of numbers in the form of a phone number and those posts will be automatically deleted.  I already have something in place just like that for other things.

I was wrong the whole time.  It actually wasn't passing the variables.  After I corrected my stupid mistake, the loading gif shows now, but the data ISN'T being passed, so i'm retrying all your suggestions again.  Thanks a lot, guys, seriously, you've done a lot.

Comment: Try `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()`

Comment: New to Jquery is not question! welcome is the community Answer

Comment: Why do some of you have to act so tough ?  Can you make your comment relevant to the question / issue ?

Comment: .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() didn't correct the issue..  thank yout hough

Comment: So, when you say everything works except the loading.gif, you mean that the data you need **is** being fetched via ajax. You just need to show the loading.gif for the users to understand that something is happening?

Comment: Try `$("#"+div_id).html('Wait, it is loading...')`. Make sure that this works. In that case the issue might be quite minor, like the path of the image

Comment: That didn't work either.  While the processfeed.php is executing, the textarea is still visible.  Nothing happens visually at all..

Comment: What does this actually mean ?  $("#"+div_id)

Comment: That means, select an element which has an `id` equal to the `div_id` variable.

Comment: This needs debugging the code line-by-line. Try commenting out the ajax bit and see if the image is visible then.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using jquery in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function loadingAjax(div_id)
        {
            $("#"+div_id).html('<center><img src="images/ajax_loader.gif"></center>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processfeed.php?<? echo   "loggedinuser=$loggedinuser&message=$message&private=$private&userto=$userto&feedpic=$feedpic&  feedpictmp=$feedpictmp";?>",
                data: "loggedinuser=" + loggedinuser,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: That wasn't it.  I just tried it.  ALso, the code executes inside a file that calls Jquery.

Comment: @user1799250 alert msg in your success also use <?php instead of <? in URL

Comment: OK, but the <? is working, so I don't understand why you're bringing that up.. ?  Alert msg in my success ?  See, this is why I made the title I'm new.  I don't understand what " alert msg in your success " actually suggests..

Comment: @user1799250 Change URL with this and let me know then-  url: "processfeed.php?"+<?php echo "loggedinuser=$loggedinuser&message=$message&private=$private&userto=$userto&feedpic=$feedpic&feedpictmp=$feedpictmp"; ?>,

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps:

1. Verify Jquery library is added in you code.
2. Check firebug or other tool to see any client side scripting error.
3. Insert some alerts or debug your code to see where it is throwing error.
4. Alert the url for ajax call and verify is it correct?

and change your script code:

```
<head>
<style>
.dvLoader
{
    right:0px;
    bottom:36px;            
    left: 234px;
    position: absolute;
    display:none;   
    top: 85px;   
    z-index: 999;  
}
.dvLoader #overlay
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;   
    background-color: Black;        
    opacity: 0.5; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);/*IE*/
    /*position: fixed;        */
    z-index: 1000;
    bottom:0;
}
.dvLoader #loaderContent
{
    background-image:url(../images/loading_box.png);      
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    width: 220px;
    z-index: 1001;
}
.dvLoader #loaderContent label
{
    color: #666666;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-left:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
     <script>
        function loadingAjax(div_id)
        {
            $('#dvLoader').show();       
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processfeed.php?<? echo   "loggedinuser=$loggedinuser&message=$message&private=$private&userto=$userto&feedpic=$feedpic&  feedpictmp=$feedpictmp";?>",
                data: "loggedinuser=" + loggedinuser,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
                    $('#dvLoader').hide();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="dvLoader" id="dvLoader">
      <div id="overlay">
      </div>
      <div id="loaderContent">
          <div>
              <label>Loading...</label>
          </div>
          <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/loader.gif")" alt="" />
      </div>
</div>
<div id="myDiv"/>
</body>
```

Comment: I really thought your alterations would work.  They look professional, but it still didn't work.  This seems like a stupid problem to be having..

Comment: I got this response.  I'm about to give up on it !  It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

remove

```
  <?php echo ....
```

in your code and ad as bellow

pass your all variable to AJAX function and create url like this.

```
function loadingAjax(div_id,loggedinuser,message,private,userto,feedpic,feedpictmp)
{

   document.getElementById("'"+div_id+"'").innerHTML = '<center><img src="images/ajax_loader.gif"></center>';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processfeed.php?loggedinuser="+loggedinuser+"&message="+message+"&private="+private+"&userto="+userto+"&feedpic="+feedpic+"&feedpictmp="+feedpictmp,
        data: "loggedinuser=" + loggedinuser,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#"+div_id).html(msg);
}
});
}
```

Comment: check my edit document.getElementById("'"+div_id+"'").innerHTML = '<center><img src="images/ajax_loader.gif"></center>';

Comment: does you file in the place where images folder also in ?